# Error (invalid length argument) while calling a function

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I am writing a function to check the mean of numeric columns in a data frame. below is the code I have written.

```
means_func <- function(x)
{
    nc <- ncol(sapply(x,is.numeric))    #selecting numeric columns only
    means <- numeric(nc)                #assigning result
    for (i in nc)
    {
    means[i] <- mean(x[i])
    }
    means
}
means_func(airquality)   #calling the function
```

But when I call the function, I get an error 
Error in numeric(nc) : invalid 'length' argument

Comment: As far as error messages go that one is pretty informative; start your debugging by running `sapply(airquality, is.numeric)` and `ncol(sapply(airquality, is.numeric))`. Also, you can greatly simplify your task with the `Filter` and `colMeans` functions.

Comment: Thanks @nrussell let me check these functions as well.